# Under Review mode to show accepted answer along with the question, with 1st new posts, or late answers

Tags: feature-request, flagging

More of a suggestion than a question I guess, but so be it.

I'm having to constantly Check the entire question when reviewing Late answers or First time new posts.

I understand it wouldn't make much sense to show the entire question with all the other answers due to possibly server resource or size, what have you, but I think it would be super helpful to at least see the accepted answer IF there is an accepted answer along side these review situations, and the Original Question.

Because I personally think If there is already an accepted answer, this will make reviewing/flagging the Late/First post much easier to handle, then to constantly have to actually go into the entire question every time you're reviewing something new.

Comment: Just because there's an accepted answer doesn't make the new answer less relevant. What if the original method is no longer useful? What if it's a new alternative solution? By judging the answer based on the content of it, you can get a pretty good idea on whether or not it's useful. If it's a duplicate answer, it will most likely be found in a different type of review.

Comment: i never said the new post is less relevant in anyway, as reviewer you want to get an idea of how relevant the accepted answer is to the new answer, without having to check the entire question. I don't even think it would take that much effort to program this into effect. And why not judge the answer based on the already accepted answer, i think its a totally relevant suggestion